# Unable to create a cordova project Error cannot find module

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

I am trying to create a `cordova 4.2.0` project but I'm getting the following error while using the create command

> Cannot find module 'internal/util/types'

Here is my configuration:

cordova 4.2.0

npm 5.6.0

node 8.10.0

According to the answers, there is a mismatch of `node.js` version and `cordova`. Which version of `node` is recommended with `cordova 4.2.0 project`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried below steps:

delete `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm`

run `npm install -g npm`

Comment: I think the issue is with the version of node. I have to set it up with cordova 4.2.0 so unable to find the exact version of node. This command will update npm. I tried doing that but the error persists

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with node. looks like node v8.2.1 works.try by upgrading or downgrading the node version.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I also think the issue is with Node version. Could you tell me the exact version to download which works with cordova 4.2.0?

Comment: I need to set up the node version according to my cordova 4.2.0 project. Would  v6.2.2 of node would be fine with it?

Comment: My cordova version is 6.5.0, i am not sure 4.2.0 works or not